# Gridview: Bind values from datatable to a column where control is dropdownlist but don't add them to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a simple dropdownlist.

- -I have some columns.
- -A column called Choose:
- -The control of the column is a dropdownlist with 2 fixed items : Yes and No.
- -In the dataTable the column "Choose" the cell has the text "nope";
- If debug my webpage , in the gridview,the column that's containing
  the dropdownlist is not showing the values from the dataTable . I want the gridview to show them .
- So , I want to show the values from the column not from the
  dropdownlist

Comment: what kind of values are you trying to display?

Comment: string value , each cell has a default value "no"

Comment: You can set a default value  "NO" in this dropBox and When u Binding the GridView, Call A select for each item inserting the values...

Comment: I don't want to insert anything in the dropdownlist , when I open the page and I see the gridview , I want to see the value "no" in all the rows and when I press edit the dropdownlist should have nothing to do with the values from the data table column

Comment: I think you'd be better off posting some example code so we can visualize what you're trying to do.

Comment: well , there's no code atm for that , I need to know how can I make the values visible.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit confusing, but it sounds like you want to select the answer from the list. If so, something like this should work:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Answer") %>'>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**EDIT**: Based on your last comment, it sounds like this is what you need:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("SomeUnrelatedValue") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You want to show the value from the column in the dropdown? So instead of "Yes" or "No" it would display the value from the column?

Comment: no , so the dropdown has nothing to do with the values in the column . I just want the values to be visible and when I click the button of gridview : edit , the dropdown to be there , something like GridView1.Column[3].Values = visible , something like that.